# Update Values on Create Function in Odoo8

Tags: python, odoo

I wanted to update field record on saving the form. I tried to write a function which will save the new values on the SAVE button. But the values dont seem to be updated. My code is below:

```
@api.model
    def create(self,values):        
        for obj in self.passports_ids:
            data=obj.passports_number   
            values.update({'passport_id':data})
        res_id=super(hrEmployee, self).create(values)   
        return res_id
```

Please help me on this on point me my mistake.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Arsalan Sherwani,

You doing wrong way. as self is doesnt exist in database,

Try below code:

```
@api.model
def create(self,values):
      for record in self.passports_ids:
          self.passport_id = record.passports_number   
    res_id=super(hrEmployee, self).create(values)   
    return res_id
```

if `passport_id` is many2one field then you need to assign object but if `passport_id` is char field then above code will do.

Bests

Comment: Error Says: Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded

Answer (score 0):

You should try following,

I don't know model name to which passports_ids belongs, so you just replace appropriate model name.

```
@api.model
def create(self,values):        
    passports_ids = values.get('passports_ids',False)
    if not passports_ids:
        return super(hrEmployee, self).create(values)

    for obj in self.env['passport_model_name'].browse(passports_ids):
        data=obj.passports_number   
        values.update({'passport_id':data})
    return super(hrEmployee, self).create(values)
```